# How to write jasmine test case for Async Pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine, angular2-forms, combinelatest

```
this.Enabled = combineLatest(this.form.get('IdGroup').get('Nbrs').valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null)),
      this.form.get('IdGroup').get('Ids').valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null)),

      (Nbrs, Ids) => {            
        return !((Nbrs instanceof Array && Nbrs.length > 0) || (Ids instanceof Array && Ids.length > 0) );
      });

<div *ngIf="Enabled | async" >
<p> Show Text </p>
</div>
```

How can i write Jasmine Unit test cases for async pipe(Enabled)?
I have tried the follwing way

```
this.form.get('IdGroup').get('Nbrs').setValue([123,2456]);

 component.Enabled.subscribe((value) => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(value).toBeTruthy();
      });
```